# How to let ignite's cast function return null instead of throwing an exception?

Tags: java, casting, ignite

When I use ignate's `cast` function, when the source data cannot be converted to target type, then ignite will throw this exception:

> javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to run map query remotely.Failed to execute map query on the node: 3ed8c3f3-31d3-4e18-a41c-83e2b6d4bf4a, class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException:Failed to execute SQL query. Cannot parse "DATE" constant "xxxx";

But I need it to use `null` instead when it cannot be converted, just like the Postgresql database.

What should I do?

Ignite version:2.6,JDBC version:2.5

```
SELECT CAST(city AS DATE) AS `a1` FROM orders GROUP BY CAST(city AS DATE);
```

Expected:

```
a1

Null
```

Actual:

```
java.sql.SQLException: javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to run map query remotely.Failed to execute map query on the node: 3ed8c3f3-31d3-4e18-a41c-83e2b6d4bf4a, class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException:Failed to execute SQL query. Cannot parse "DATE" constant "xxxx"; SQL statement:
SELECT
CAST(__Z0.city AS DATE) __C0_0
FROM PUBLIC.ORDERS2 __Z0
GROUP BY CAST(__Z0.city AS DATE) LIMIT 3 [22007-195]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinConnection.sendRequest(JdbcThinConnection.java:751)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute0(JdbcThinStatement.java:210)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinPreparedStatement.executeWithArguments(JdbcThinPreparedStatement.java:252)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcThinPreparedStatement.java:78)
at com.uniplore.calculation.connectors.IgniteConnector.execute(IgniteConnector.java:58)
at tests.AbstractFunctionTransTest.getResult(AbstractFunctionTransTest.java:65)
at tests.IgniteFunctionTransTest.Date(IgniteFunctionTransTest.java:840)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that how PostgreSQL's `CAST` work? [This post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203934/postgresql-alternative-to-sql-server-s-try-cast-function) kind of suggests otherwise.

In any case, you can't change this behavior in Ignite. If you use the same value `xxxx` as a placeholder date, you can use `CASE` as a workaround:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN city = 'xxxx' THEN NULL ELSE CAST(city AS DATE) END AS a1 
FROM orders GROUP BY a1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok,I know,CAST is a standard function that should return exceptions。

Mysql has a function called DATE that can return NULL values when the conversion fails，except ignite has no corresponding function.

The best way is to return the error to the user, or let the user use the PARSEDATETIME function instead.